# First principal component for two variables?

Tags: pca

Proof that if two variables (X, Y) have covariance S= $\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}$, then proof that if c $\neq$ 0, then the first principal component is $\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2+(V_1-a)^2}X}+\frac{c}{|c|}\sqrt{\frac{(V_1-a)â}{c^2+(V_1-a)^2}Y}$

Where $V_1$ is the variance explained by the first principal component.

I tried finding the eigenvalues and eigenvector of S, but couldn't, so I tried substituting $V_1$ and trying to find another solution, but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is just computing the top eigenvector and eigenvalues of a 2x2 symmetric matrix and interpreting it in the context of PCA. For a generic 2x2 matrix $A := \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ we can find the eigenvalues by
$$
p_A(\lambda) = \det\left(A - \lambda I\right)
$$
$$
= (a-\lambda)(d-\lambda) - bc \\
= \lambda^2 -\lambda (a+d) + ad - bc \\
= \lambda^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)\lambda + \det A.
$$
Setting this to zero yields
$$
\lambda = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(A) \pm \sqrt{(\operatorname{tr} A)^2 - 4\det A}}{2}.
$$

For PCA we'll be interested in $\lambda_1$, the largest eigenvalue.

---

For the eigenvectors, we need to solve the system
$$
Sv = \lambda v \\
\iff (S - \lambda I)v = \mathbf 0
$$
with $v \in \mathbb R^2$ and $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue. The eigenvalues are chosen to be such that $S - \lambda I$ is singular which means without even needing to do the arithmetic this'll row reduce to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a-\lambda & b \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v = \mathbf 0
$$
since $b \neq 0$ so for an arbitrary eigenvalue I'll need to have $(a-\lambda)v_1 + bv_2 = 0$. And again because $b \neq 0$ by assumption we’ll get 
$$
v_2 = \frac{\lambda - a}{b} v_1.
$$
I want to choose my eigenvectors to be unit vectors so
$$
v_1^2 + \left(\frac{\lambda - a}{b} \right)^2v_1^2 = 1 \\
\implies v_1^2 = \left(1 + \left(\frac{\lambda - a}{b} \right)^2\right)^{-1} \\
= \frac{b^2}{b^2 + (\lambda - a)^2}.
$$
Eigenvectors can be scaled so I can just take the positive square root. I'll then have
$$
v_2 = \frac{\lambda - a}{b}\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{b^2 + (\lambda - a)^2}}.
$$

After some rearranging and using $\lambda=\lambda_1$ we have everything we need to finish the result so I'll leave it here.